# What are variable weights in principal component analysis (PCA) using MATLAB?

Tags: pca, matlab

Can I set variable (inputs) weights in MATLAB for principal component analysis using `pca()` function? There is `VariableWeights` input parameter for `pca()`. If yes, how does MATLAB use this weights in PCA calculation? In my case some inputs have more higher weights in final output compare to other inputs and I want convert all (6) inputs to a single input.

Comment: It would be very nice if you show us a snippet: data, weights, the `matlab` command, printout of results. It may help detect how those weights are being used.

Comment: Have you consulted [Matlab's help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html)? From your question it is not very clear. All inputs to `pca()` are explained there, and examples given.

Comment: Not sure about the MATLAB implementation, but you should be able to scale features with different variances to reweight. In R, the typical procedure is `prcomp(..., scale=T)`, which scales all features for mean 0 and variance 1. Rescaling yourself with variances equal to the desired weights, and then setting `scale=F` (or the MATLAB equivalent), should get you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB will apply Variable Weights multipliers to the variables before running PCA on them.

A typical usage of this input is to compute PCA on the correlation matrix instead of the covariance. In this case you set 'Centered' true and supply inverse variances as weights vector or simply set it to 'variance'.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So there isn't any method to set inputs (features) weights in PCA?

Comment: @user2991243 I would flip your question and say that maybe you should use PCA loadings as features weights? It's not clear to me why would you do PCA if you already know the weights

Comment: This is a good question. Beside this how can i use weights in `PCA` calculation. Suppose that first input is more important for us (so has higher weight). How can I use this information to calculate `PCA`? We want first input (or other specific inputs) has higher weights for calculation and higher effects in final results.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on why exactly you want to use PCA? Is the objective dimensionality reduction or something else?

Comment: I want convent 6 features to 1 feature to create an index of these 6 features. In my case some features have higher weight (importance) compare to other features.

Comment: So, my question is why you want one feature from 6? Why not use all six? And if you already have an idea of the "importance" of features, then why don't use these weights without messing with PCA?